# OO JS Object doesn't support this property or method in IE8

Tags: javascript, oop, internet-explorer-8

I am currently experiencing some IE8 bugs related to OOP JavaScript. Everything works fine in IE9+, chrome, firefox etc. I have also tried to find similar issues on stackoverflow, but failed.

**Code:**

```
$(function(){
    // Notification
    OPD_Notification = function( selector ) {
        this.selector = selector;
    }

    OPD_Notification.prototype.setText = function( text ) {
        $(this.selector).find('.container').text(text);
    };

    OPD_Notification.prototype.setStatus = function( status ) {
        $(this.selector).addClass(status);
    }

    OPD_Notification.prototype.removeStatus = function( status ) {
        $(this.selector).removeClass(status);
    }

    OPD_Notification.prototype.show = function() {
        $(this.selector).slideDown(200);
    };

    OPD_Notification.prototype.hide = function() {
        $(this.selector).slideUp(200);
    };

    // Notification
    notification = new OPD_Notification('#notification');
});
```

**Problem:**
IE8 throws me an error `Object doesn't support this property or method` when I try to do following: `notification = new OPD_Notification('#notification');` I guess it might be something to do with jQuery, but not really sure.

As if I run code bellow, it works fine in IE8.

```
function Rabbit( line ) {
    this.line = line;
}

Rabbit.prototype.speak = function() {
    alert(this.line);
};

rbt = new Rabbit("Well, now you're asking me.");
rbt.speak();
```

Any tips on what I am doing wrong, would help a lot. Thanks.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8387R/)**

Comment: Are your variables supposed to be global?

Comment: @elclanrs Yes. As I want to use it in some other functions as well.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream/issues/283#issuecomment-7835157

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how, and don't know why. But I've changed `notification = new OPD_Notification('#notification');` to `prefixNotification = new OPD_Notification('#notification');` and it started working.